# Nested word series [humans only]

Tags: wordplay, no-computers

**[This is just a fun little puzzle for humans.  We'll see you next time, computers!]**

It's interesting to think about words contained in other words.  How often do we notice, for example, that VOLCANOES contains the word CANOES, or that CONCERNS contains the word ONCE?

But why stop there?  We can find words within words within words, nested like Russian dolls.

The most impressive nested series I've found are 9 levels, like this:

```
REARRANGEMENTS
  ARRANGEMENTS
  ARRANGEMENT
  ARRANGE
    RANGE
    RANG
    RAN
     AN
     A
```

But why be content with contiguous letters only?  How about nested words in which the letters selected are not contiguous in the parent?

For example, REPUDIATE contains the word EDIT, only that the letters E-D-I-T are not necessarily contiguous.

(However, they must be in the same order in the child word as they are in the parent word.)

Here's how a nested series with noncontinuous letters might look.  The starting word is NONREPRESENTATIONAL:

```
NONREPRESENTATIONAL
   REPRESENTATIONAL
   REPRESENTATION
     PRESENTATION
        S  TATION
        S  TAT IN
        S  TA  IN
        S      IN
               IN
               I

I.e., NONREPRESENTATIONAL, REPRESENTATIONAL, REPRESENTATION, PRESENTATION, STATION, STATIN, STAIN, SIN, IN, I
```

In each case below, I have given you the starting word.  See if you can find the indicated number of nested levels.

1. Start with TRANSCENDENTALISTS and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
2. Start with INTERRELATIONSHIPS and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
3. Start with SLAUGHTERHOUSES and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
4. Start with STARTLINGLY and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
5. Start with INTEGRATIONISTS and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
6. Start with NONCONFRONTATIONAL and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
7. Start with NONDENOMINATIONAL and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
8. Start with DECONSTRUCTIONISTS and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
9. Start with CRAFTSPERSONS and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
10. Start with CONTRAINDICATIONS and see if you can find 9 more nested levels
11. Start with RESTORATIONISTS and see if you can find 10 more nested levels
12. Start with UNCHARACTERISTICALLY and see if you can find 10 more nested levels

P.S. — I should have noted upfront that I construct my puzzles so as to be solvable with only very well-known words.  (Otherwise, I risk incurring the wrath of the Scrabble community by casting aspersions on words like AE!)

---

Excellent work, @North @OmegaKrypton and @JonMarkPerry !

I was expecting someone to say, "How dare you malign AE!  It's a perfectly cromulent word..."

Epilogue on #1:

> Thank you for using the wonderful mathematical term TRANSCENDENTALS.
>
>     For those not comfortable with a word from a specialized field, here is an alternative solution:
>
>     TRANSCENDENTALISTS
>     TRANSCENDENTALIST
>     TRANSCENDENTAL
>     TRANSCENDENT
>     TRANSCEND
>     TRANCE
>     TRACE
>     RACE
>     ACE
>     A

Note on #7:

> There still seems to be a typo in the solution for #7.
>
>     Here is another solution:
>
>     NONDENOMINATIONAL
>     DENOMINATIONAL
>     DENOMINATION
>     DOMINATION
>     DOMINION
>     DOMINO
>     DINO
>     DIN
>     IN
>     I

Comment: Holy moly sweet mother of mary this should be fun

Comment: When you say find nine more nested level are you asking for a total of nine or total of ten including that word

Comment: I'd say 9 more, personally -- so total of 10 including the first word, but I could be wrong!

Comment: @North — I'm saying, I have given you the base word, now go and find 9 *additional* words nested within it.  So, in my given example above, the base word is NONREPRESENTATIONAL and then there are an additional 9 nested levels.  BTW, I see in your answer to TRANSCENDENTALISTS that you have only provided an additional 8 nested levels.

Comment: @SlowMagic Done! That was tons of fun, I really enjoyed it. My answers are slightly different from OmegaKrypton's findings, but every number is unique (I didn't just STEAL OmegaKrypton's work)

Comment: @SlowMagic *NOW* I've finished ;) Thanks for the challenge!

Comment: Also fear te wrath of Scrabble... we the elitist community of the English language use words that no humans should ever use but we know them anyways just to flex our knowledge :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1)

> TRANSCENDENTALISTS
> TRANSCENDENTALIST
> TRANSCENDENTALS (@JonMarkPerry thx)
> TRANSCENDENTAL
> TRANSCENDENT
> TRANSCEND
> ASCEND
> ACED
> ACE
> A

2)

> INTERRELATIONSHIPS
> INTERRELATIONSHIP
> INTERRELATIONS
> INTERRELATION
> RELATION
> RATION
> RAIN
> RAN
> AN
> A

3)

> SLAUGHTERHOUSES
> SLAUGHTERHOUSE
> SLAUGHTERS
> SLAUGHTER
> LAUGHTER
> LATER
> LATE
> ATE
> AT
> A

4)

> STARTLINGLY
> STARTLING
> STARTING
> STARING
> STRING
> STING
> SING
> SIN
> IN
> I

5)

> INTEGRATIONISTS
> INTEGRATIONIST
> INTEGRATIONS
> INTEGRATION
> INGRAIN
> GRAIN
> RAIN
> RAN
> AN
> A

6)

> NONCONFRONTATIONAL
> CONFRONTATIONAL
> CONFRONTATION
> CORONATION
> ORATION
> RATION
> RATIO
> RAT
> AT
> A

7)

> NONDENOMINATIONAL
> DENOMINATIONAL
> DENOMINATION
> DOMINATION
> DOMINION
> DOMAIN
> MAIN
> MAN
> AN
> A

8)

> DECONSTRUCTIONISTS
> DECONSTRUCTIONIST
> DECONSTRUCTIONS
> DECONSTRUCTION
> CONSTRUCTION
> SUCTION
> SCION
> ION
> IN
> I

9) (@OmegaKrypton did majority of the work, just fixed a couple stuff, upvote theirstuff y'all)

> CRAFTSPERSONS
> CRAFTSPERSON
> CRAFTERS
> CRATERS
> CRATES
> RATES
> RATE
> RAT
> AT
> A

10)

> CONTRAINDICATIONS
> CONTRAINDICATION
> CONTRADICTION
> CONTRACTION
> CONTRACT
> CONTACT
> TACT
> ACT
> AT
> A

11) (again, @OmegaKrypton for majority of the stuff. Just slight adjustments.)

> RESTORATIONISTS
> RESTORATIONIST
> RESTORATIONS
> RESTORATION
> RESTRAIN
> STRAIN
> TRAIN
> RAIN
> RAN
> AN
> A

12) (note @OmegaKrypton did most of the work, I just adjusted it slight; so upvote their answer!)

> UNCHARACTERISTICALLY
> CHARACTERISTICALLY
> CHARACTERISTIC
> CHARACTERS
> CHARACTER
> CHARTER
> CHART
> CART
> ART
> AT
> A

Comment: More's gonna come, I just don't wanna get sniped

Comment: I think for number 1, you should do r13( NFPRAQ -> FRAQ -> RAQ -> RA -> N ) which will get you one extra line...

Comment: @El-Guest thank you, but how can I get from r13(RA-> N) without that letter being inside of it?

Comment: @El-Guest Also found an alternative solution (the stuff you learn from scrabble)

Comment: TRANSCENDENTALS?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry that also works... guess didnt think of that but rot13(nr) also works

Comment: dang, sniped 5 from me as i was finishing up

Comment: 6 has a rogue letter there

Comment: You're doing great so far!  I'm a pretty lenient grader, but I'm having a hard time with AE in #1.  Suggestion:  I would rework everything after TRANSCEND.

Comment: @SlowMagic decided to take JonMark Perry's advice :P. Ae is a legit word though, meaning one https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ae Don't worry, I didn't use any outside help; I play Scrabble semi-competitively, and have so far memorized every two-letter word that's playable, which is how I know ae is a word. Speaking of which, I should be studying more words later

Comment: You might also try finishing up with rot13(GENAFPRAQ → GENPRQ → ENPRQ → NPRQ → NPR → N) allowing you to either remove a more questionable earlier word, or (if you're satisfied with all of them) beating the requirements.

Comment: You're almost there!  Just a few little things:  #6 needs another level (suggestion: there is another great word you can get out of CONFRONTATION).  #7 has the same word twice, and also has a child word that could not have come from the parent word.  #9 needs another level (suggestion: go in a different direction after CRAFTERS).

Answer (score 9):

9

> CRAFTSPERSONS
> CRAFTSPERSON
> CRAFTERS
> CRATERS
> CRATER
> RATER
> RATE
> ATE
> AE
> A

11

> RESTORATIONISTS
>  RESTORATIONIST
>  RESTORATIONS
>  RESTORATION
>  RORATION [Thanks jafe]
>  ORATION [Thanks North]
>  RATION
>  RAIN
>  RAN
>  AN
>  A

12

> UNCHARACTERISTICALLY
>  CHARACTERISTICALLY
>  CHARACTERISTIC
>  CHARACTER
>  CHARTER
>  CHART
>  HART
>  HAT
>  HA
>  A

Comment: how about rot13(bengvba)

Comment: It's a word, apparently

Comment: You're doing great so far!  I'm a pretty lenient grader, but I'm having a hard time with CHARACTERISTICAL.  Suggestion:  There is more you can do after CHART than what you currently have.  That might give you an additional level to compensate for the loss of CHARACTERISTICAL.

Comment: [Additional one for 11](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/roration) ;)

Comment: FYI, #9 needs another level (suggestion: go in a different direction after CRAFTERS).  Also, at the risk of incurring the wrath of the Scrabble community and @North, I am casting aspersions on AE (if no other reason than I work hard to ensure all of my solutions involve very well-known words, so it would be a shame to miss out on them!)

Answer (score 6):

These don't appear to always have a unique answer. For example:

> INTERRELATIONSHIPS
>  INTERRELATIONSHIP
>  INTERRELATIONS
>  INTERRELATION
>  RELATION
>  ELATION
>  LION
>  ION
>  IN
>  I

differs from @north's after RELATION -> RATION, or RELATION -> ELATION. But I only found a 4 letter word next anyway.

Comment: Yes, I like this alternative as well, because it follows a different path from the other -ation- words, and because it includes a certain charismatic animal!